# How can I improve the performance of a recursive component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native Expo project, I have created a recursive comment component that calls itself, in order to render a nested comment thread.

However, once the number of comments gets too large the performance starts to degrade where it is not very user friendly.I have tried altering the structure of how the api calls to retrieve that comments and some other minor tweaks but to no avail.

I figure I need to use shouldComponentUpdate in some fashion to only re-render when certain state has changed, mainly whether or not a comment is open or collapsed.

Are there any ways to improve performance of a recursive component in React?

```
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import dateFns from "date-fns";
import { inject } from "mobx-react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from "react-native";
import Collapsible from "react-native-collapsible";
import HTMLView from "react-native-htmlview";
import { Text, withTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import ApiService from "../services/ApiService";

class Comment extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    api: PropTypes.instanceOf(ApiService).isRequired,
    commentIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired
  };

  state = {
    comments: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStoryComments();
  }

  async fetchStoryComments() {
    const { api, commentIds } = this.props;
    try {
      let comments = await api.fetchStoryComments(commentIds);
      comments = comments.map(comment => {
        const commentCopy = comment;
        commentCopy.isCollapsed = false;
        return commentCopy;
      });
      this.setState({
        comments
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // HANDLE ERROR
    }
  }

  toggleCollapse(commentId) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      comments: prevState.comments.map(comment =>
        comment.id === commentId
          ? Object.assign(comment, { isCollapsed: !comment.isCollapsed })
          : comment
      )
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { comments } = this.state;
    const { api } = this.props;

    return comments ? (
      comments.map(
        comment =>
          comment && (
            <View key={comment.id} style={styles.commentContainer}>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => this.toggleCollapse(comment.id)}
              >
                <View style={styles.commentHeader}>
                  <Text style={styles.commentHeaderText}>
                    {`${comment.by} ${dateFns.distanceInWordsToNow(
                      new Date(comment.time * 1000)
                    )} ago`}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.commentHeaderText}>
                    {comment.isCollapsed ? (
                      <FontAwesome name="plus" />
                    ) : (
                      <FontAwesome name="minus" />
                    )}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Collapsible duration={200} collapsed={comment.isCollapsed}>
                <View style={styles.comment}>
                  <HTMLView
                    addLineBreaks={false}
                    stylesheet={htmlStyles}
                    textComponentProps={{ style: styles.commentText }}
                    value={comment.text}
                  />
                  {"kids" in comment && (
                    <View style={styles.kids}>
                      <Comment api={api} commentIds={comment.kids} />
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </Collapsible>
            </View>
          )
      )
    ) : (
      <ActivityIndicator
        style={styles.activityIndicator}
        size="small"
        color="#fff"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default inject("api")(withTheme(Comment));
```

Comment: limit the amount of recursive iterations and hide the rest behind a "see more"

Comment: Yeah, I've contemplated this. It might not be a bad idea for a temporary fix, but not as great user experience in the long run..

Comment: Why not? Most all big sites incorporate this somehow - facebook, twitter, even stackoverflow

Comment: That's true. I'll definitely keep that as an option. I'd prefer an infinite scroll similar to a FlatList component.

Comment: Here's a great article about why infinite scroll might be a bad idea: https://logrocket.com/blog/infinite-scroll/

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I like reading articles like this.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a [flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) instead of mapping a bunch of views?

here is a [guide](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) explaining how to use it.

Edit 1:

You can actually use a [sectionlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) which is like [flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) for complex structures like the one you are building.

here is a small example:

```
render() {
    const a = ['comment 1 a', 'comment 2 a', 'comment 3 a'];
    const b = ['comment 1 b', 'comment 2 b'];
    const c = ['comment 1 c'];

    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop : (Platform.OS) == 'ios' ? 20 : 0 }}>
        <SectionList
          sections={[
            { comment: 'Comment a with subcomponents a', data: a },
            { comment: 'Comment b with subcomponents b', data: b },
            { comment: 'Comment c with subcomponents c', data: c },
          ]}
          renderSectionHeader={ ({section}) => <Text> { section.comment } </Text> }
          renderItem={ ({item}) => <Text> { item } </Text> }
          keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index }
        />
      </View> 
    );
  }
```

where the `data` field in the section list could be an array of components,
hope this help.

Comment: I tried Flatlist briefly, but I was running into issues with nesting Flatlists within Flatlists due to the nature of comment threading. Maybe I was going about it wrong.   Could you provide a high level example about how you would convert it to a FlatList?

Comment: I edit the post with a small example, hope can be helpful

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot.